# How does one remove a selected area in layout that has seemingly frozen in place? (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, layouts

I was editing one of my layouts when this happened (see picture). I was using the select/move item command when I unintentionally "selected" a square, and instead of it just disappearing, like it usually does when I release, it froze. I have been unsuccessful at removing it, and I have in trying to do so managed to create three more..
I have tried to close and reopen. I tried to save as an image, but the selected areas are saved onto the image as well.
Has anyone here encountered this problem before, and have any idea on how to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is a [bug](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/46569) that seems fixed.

In the meantime, you can select everything, copy, create a new layout, paste